# Universal image loader library is acting slow on Android 5.0 as compared to Android 4.4.4

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, universal-image-loader

I am using

https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader

for loading images in my application. It was working fine till the time I was using Android 4.4.4 on my Nexus 5 but after upgrading my Android version to 5.0 I can feel that image loading process has become slow in my ListView. I haven't touched the code so I am really not able to understand the reason for the issue.

To double check the doubt, I took another Nexus 5 which was running Android 4.4.4 and it performed better than the Nexus running Android 5.0. I am really not able to understand the reason for this performance issue.

Need help to ensure the same smooth experience when it comes to image loading as I don't have any clue what could cause this degradation in performance.

Comment: Do you mean speed of image loading or some lags while scroll list?

Comment: I mean speed of image loading. I am using 160 x 160 images of size between 3 to 4 KB. It loads within a fraction of second on 4.4.4 even on 2G connection but on 5.0, it takes like 2-3 sec for the image to load.

Comment: Can you show ImageLoader's logs with timestamps?

Comment: Hi @NOSTRA. Apologies for replying late. Please access the logs using the provided link.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/izdk4i63n2zuqad/image_loader_log.txt?dl=0

Note: I am getting close to 300 products using Async task and displaying their text information along with these images in a single activity. The issue still persists that image loading is really slow when it comes to Android 5.0

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your application it's optimized for the Dalvik Runtime, which it's used on android versions below Lollipop (Android <= KitKat).

Android Lollipop Uses by default the new Runtime called ART (Android Run Time), which replaces the old Dalvik runtime or virtual machine, which it's an implementation of the Java Virtual Machine adapted for Android devices.

I'm not 100% this is your issue, but if you haven't touch the code, it's related to the Android OS, and this is one of the major changes on Lollipop.

If you still have the Nexux running KitKat and want to confirm what i'm writing here, go to developer options, enable the ART and test your app using ART instead of Dalvik.